# Wpf Tree View Searching

Tags: wpf, treeview

How do i search for a node in very large treeview , i am using on-demand loading of nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little light on details. For example, I would be curious to know if this is a user-specified search and what the search criteria would look like. In any case, I'll take a stab at giving you a general answer to your general question:

WPF makes it easier than ever to base the view on a data model structure of your own choosing, rather than the other way around.

I would suggest creating an object model that represents the underlying data (you may have this already) and "bind" it to the tree view via data templates (specifically the [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx)). Define your search in terms of the data structure, not the view.

Comment: Thanks Daniel
i am doing exactly the same thing as you are saying but if user is supplying a search value and that value belongs to a node which is not loaded yet than i need to load it than search it but it takes a hell lot of time i am ding recursive search in my model

Comment: How are you storing the data that gets loaded into the treeview?